# Copy Table from one to another server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can any body let me know how can we copy a table with the data in it exactly to another server. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to script out both the schema and the data as INSERTs: [SQL Server 2008: Script Data as Inserts](http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com/2009/07/sql-server-2008-script-data-as-inserts.html)

Answer (score 5):

Use the SSIS wizard. Right click on the database node in management studio and click on "Export Data". Follow this wizard to specify the source and destination servers. This will copy your table and all data in it.

Answer (score 2):

In SSMS you can right click on the table -> Script Table As -> Create To -> (whatever). It will give you the structure of the table.

To copy data you can use [bcp utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx).